# where is the implementation of functions in syscalls.h within linux kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, system-calls

I am trying to find the implementation codes of the functions defined in `syscalls.h` of linux kernel. For example, I see the following function prototype in `syscalls.h` file

```
asmlinkage long sys_gethostname(char __user *name, int len);
asmlinkage long sys_sethostname(char __user *name, int len);
asmlinkage long sys_setdomainname(char __user *name, int len);
asmlinkage long sys_newuname(struct new_utsname __user *name);
asmlinkage long sys_uname(struct old_utsname __user *);
asmlinkage long sys_olduname(struct oldold_utsname __user *);
```

But I cannot find the actually implementation in my linux source directory. I am particularly interested in the implementation about the `sys_uname` function. Can some one help me where I can find it in the linux source tree? I am using ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 4):

The definitions are hard to find because they use macros.

```
grep sys_uname **/*.[ch]
```

finds a few uses but no implementation. But look for `SYSCALL_DEFINE` and...

```
grep 'SYSCALL_DEFINED.*uname' **/*.[ch]
```

and you get this:

```
kernel/sys.c:SYSCALL_DEFINE1(newuname, struct new_utsname __user *, name)
kernel/sys.c:SYSCALL_DEFINE1(uname, struct old_utsname __user *, name)
kernel/sys.c:SYSCALL_DEFINE1(olduname, struct oldold_utsname __user *, name)
```

There's no guarantee the macros won't be redesigned at some future time, and besides that there are other things that are similarly hard to find, so here's a trick I use to find stuff: go to a tree where you've actually compiled a kernel, and grep the object files.

```
nm -A **/*.o | grep sys_uname
```

The results (with boring stuff cut out) are:

```
kernel/built-in.o:000000000001258b T sys_uname
kernel/sys.o:00000000000023df T sys_uname
vmlinux.o:00000000000391a3 T sys_uname
```

`vmlinux.o` is basically the whole kernel, so of course sys_uname is in there. That doesn't tell us anything. `built-in.o` in any directory made of all the object files from that directory linked together (excluding modules - just the built-ins), so ignore that too. If you get any lines with `U` and no address, ignore those. What's left is the answer: `kernel/sys.o` is the object file, so `kernel/sys.c` is the source.

This method fails if you're looking for the implementation of something that is purely a macro, or that isn't actually included on your compiled kernel's configuration, since it won't be in the object files.

Answer (score 1):

They are generated automatically.  See the code in (e.g., for x86) arch/x86/syscalls.  With sys_uname() specifically, you will note that there are actually several implementations (sys_olduname, sys_uname, sys_newuname) depending on the syscall number and processor mode of the calling process.

Comment: I didn't see the file arch/x86/syscalls in my source tree? Is it generated during `make` process? Could you please give me more details about it?

Comment: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/syscalls